# Need Help in cronjob use in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, cron

Need help How to add Cron job in wordpress 
whats the good plugin or need to use core functions for it 
thank you in advance

Comment: You have cpanel or not

Comment: Yes i am having 
thanks for reply

Comment: Is there way with any Plugin OR something

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event ?

Comment: ok login in cpanel and find cron i means search cron and click and set time and set path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress has some default functionality to help with scheduled tasks, however, these are considered 'pseudo' CRON jobs as they check their scheduling and run when the site is loaded, instead of on a specific schedule:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron

Alternatively, you can write your own AJAX listener that can run tasks when the specific URL is called via a CRON task (entered in cPanel or the like):

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)

Comment: Thank you sorry for late reply i will surely use this its night here so i will message you